# Algorithm for generating a 3d cylinder along a path

Tags: c++, algorithm, 3d, indices, vertices

How would one go ahead and generate a cylinder that follows a path? The path is connected using nodes, and smoothing is not needed, just a hard edged long cylinder. The cylinder should be stored using a triangle list, so both vertices and indices is required.

Comment: Start witch creating orientated circles along the path and then 'connect' these circles with triangles.

Comment: Yes, but my mind is battling with the indices, how I would connect them, in a smart fashion.

Comment: Just think about quads first. You loop around the circle and take 2 vertices from the current circle and make a quad with the same 2 vertices from the next circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "unwrap" the cylinder mesh, you get a regular rectangular grid with rectangles split in two triangles.

Every vertex can be indexed by a pair of integers, from 0 to M-1 and from 0 to N-1 (with vertexes (I,0) and (I,N) being identical). Then turn every pair (I, J) to the single number I+J.M.

The triangles join the vertexes (I, J), (I+1, J), (I+1, J+1), or the vertexes (I, J), (I, J+1), (I+1, J+1).